# Formula within Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to copy contents of cell A2 ("SE0001") to paste into cell A3 to result ("SE0002").  Please help with formula.

Comment: Put `=A2` in cell A3? Your question is extremely vague.

Comment: I want to copy contents in cell A2 which is "SE0001" and paste into cell A3 but it needs to result in "SE0002".  Not sure how else to say this.

Comment: So you're not copying, but you want it to be incremented? Does it need to be updated? Excel is intelligent enough to auto-increment if you fill a column with the lower-right black handle.

Comment: correct.  the next cell would be incremented to SE0002 and SE0003 and so on.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put:

```
="SE"&TEXT(ROW()-1,"0000")
```

in A2 then fill down. That will give you what you're asking for, if you need something more general, edit your question (or ask a new one).